# How to construct the graph from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have the following adjacency matrix:

```
   a  b  c  d 
a [0, 0, 1, 1]
b [0, 0, 1, 0]
c [1, 1, 0, 1]
d [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

How do I draw the graph, given its adjacency matrix above (I've added `a,b,c,d` to label vertices).

I don't understand how the vertex $d$ (e.g., the row $d$) is adjacent to the vertex $b$, but the vertex $b$ (the row $b$) is not adjacent to the vertex $d$ (the column $d$).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Maybe it's directed?  If so, would that explain why d --> b, but b =/ d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a directed graph, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
a & & b\\
 \updownarrow  & X & \uparrow\\
c &\leftrightarrow & d
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

where I used $X$ to denote a double-sided link between  $a$-$d$ and $c$-$d$.

The direction of the edges is convention defined and could be reversed.

Comment: It looks like there is a double sided link between a and c. I don't see it in your solution.

Comment: Right, corrected.